# VBA to get information fom div id

Tags: html, excel, vba

I was trying to retrieve information from an id, but i simply couldnt.

Can any of you guys help me?

html:

```
<div id="conteudo" align="center">
    <div id="cabecaRegistro"></div>
    <div id="warning" align="left">

                    Não é possível incluir mais faturas para este…"
```

I need to retrieve the innertext for this id "warning" and tried it like:

```
objIE.Document.getElementsById("warning").innertext = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Value
```

but it didn't work.. is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you show your current state of your code at be more specific about what's "not working"?!

Comment: You have your assignment the wrong way around ,and it's `getElementById`, not `getElement*s*ById`

Comment: Thank you Tim, I it was this "S" that was driving me crazy, tyvm.